# Postgres: Adding JSONB data as new field in existing JSONB data on select

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I would like to merge two JSONB data to one, by making one set of JSONB data a new field.

JSONB data 1: `{'a':'b'}`

JSONB data 2: `{'c':'d', 'e':'f'}`

Result: `{'a':'b', 'x':{'c':'d', 'e':'f'}}`

Something like this:

```
select (i.data || '{'x':u.data}'::jsonb) as data from doc_issue as i, doc_user as u where i.data ->> 'UserId' = u.data ->> 'Id';
```

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
select i.data || jsonb_build_object('x', u.data) as data 
from doc_issue as i
inner join doc_user as u on i.data ->> 'UserId' = u.data ->> 'Id'
```